# Upgraded to PHP 7.1 - GD or ImageMagick is required

Tags: php, imagick, requirements

This question relates to two Craft sites running on the same server. One site is a production version, the other is staging. I use WHM v68 and EasyApache 4.

Production is on PHP 5.5.38. Staging is on PHP 7.0.25. Both sites report the following from admin/utils/phpinfo:

- imagick module version: 3.4.3
- Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-1 Q16 x86_64 2016-10-13

I would like to upgrade both sites to PHP 7.1, starting with staging. When I use WHM's MultiPHP Manager to update staging to PHP 7.1, I'm unable to load Craft. I receive this message:

--

**Can’t run Craft CMS :(**

Your server doesn’t meet the following requirements to run Craft CMS:

- GD or ImageMagick is required, however ImageMagick is recommended as it adds animated GIF support, and preserves 8-bit and 24-bit PNGs during image transforms.
- GD or ImageMagick is required, however ImageMagick is recommended as it adds animated GIF support, and preserves 8-bit and 24-bit PNGs during image transforms.
  Please talk to your host/IT department about upgrading your server.

--

I don't understand this because I know that ImageMagick and imagick are both installed and enabled. And imagick 3.4.3 ([since RC1](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick&release=3.4.3)) should support PHP 7.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to contact your hosting provider. There are any number of ways that this "PHP switching" can be implemented, but typically each major PHP version has its own separate modules/config files that tell it which modules to use.

So the fact that ImageMagick is installed on the server doesn't mean that it's globally available to every PHP version that's running. So, contact your hosting provider.

Also, I feel obligated to mention that boutique hosting environments can be a source of issues like this, so I try to avoid them, as per: [How Agencies & Freelancers Should Do Web Hosting](https://nystudio107.com/blog/web-hosting-for-agencies-freelancers)

Comment: Thanks @khalwat. It turns out that Imagick did need to be installed for PHP 7.1.

FWIW, we do use VPS any time we can.